# I wish I could get a new Finder window launched if I double-click the Finder icon in the dock. Is this possible?

Tags: finder, dock, utilities

I wish I could get a new Finder window launched if I double-click the Finder icon in the dock. I'm not sure if this would be possible with an Automator script, or if I would have to try to program some type menubar software or something. Any ideas?

thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

[Hyperdock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.de/) will let you do something similar. It doesn't seem to support double clicking, but I have my system set up so a middle-click on the finder icon opens a new window.

It's also an awesome dock enhancement, and brings the dock much closer to the usability of the windows taskbar (i.e. you can switch to a specific other window without having to use expose or alt-tab).

Comment: By the way you can specifically switch to another window without that: Right click an application in the Dock to see a menu of all open windows.

Comment: Still a 2-click solution to a one-click problem.

Comment: This is not a solution to the question asked. It is, however, pretty cool.

Answer (score 6):

The following AppleScript does what you want:

```
on run
    tell application "Finder"
        make new Finder window
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

Open **Script Editor** in the `/Applications/AppleScript` folder, and paste the above in to a new script. Save it somewhere as a "File Format: Application" with "Stay Open" not checked.

[image: Save Options]

Then drag that application to your Dock. When you click it, the Finder will be brought to the front and with a new finder window.

The disadvantage is, this takes about 1.5 - 2 seconds to run on my machine. I could probably tweak it by making the script stay open and watch for being brought to the front... You might also get better performance by saving it as a normal script in your "Scripts" folder and putting it in the scripts menu.

Answer (score 3):

All you're trying to do is open a new Finder window, yes?

[image: Finder Dock shortcuts]

Why not just right-click on the Finder icon in the Dock and choose "New Finder Window"?

Comment: Although an elegant solution, the OP wants to double click, hence the question ;)

Comment: Why is your context menu black? :-)

Comment: @Martín - that's why I didn't answer at first—but after I saw the upvotes for @Fake's answer (which also didn't use double-click), I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Josh - I thought that gray (or black-ish) was the norm for dock context menus in SL (as seen [here](http://www.maclife.com/article/feature/100_snow_leopard_tips_tricks_and_features?page=0,4#node-article-4789), [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=743110&p=8053305), [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=743110&p=8053603), and [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=743110&p=8055196)). If I installed something that makes them custom, I have no idea what it is — [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com), maybe?

Comment: @Josh Context menus are black in Snow Leopard.

Comment: @Martín Ah ha, that's it. I'm still on plain ol Leopard :-)